# malloc: *** error for object 0x147606ac0: pointer being realloc'd was not allocated

Tags: c, malloc, dynamic-memory-allocation, realloc

I am trying to work on dynamic memory in C. I encountered a weird issue where I get an error `malloc: *** error for object 0x147606ac0: pointer being realloc'd was not allocated`. I am trying to realloc a memory block depending on the value in the `size` variable which increments every time the loop executes. If I try to do the realloc in a function it is throwing the error, but if I do it in the same scope where the variable is defined, it works properly.

```
struct client_detail
{
    int id, fd;
};

struct group_member
{
    int id, fd, isAdmin;
};

struct group_detail
{
    int id, isBroadcastOnly, size;
    struct group_member members[5];
};

//`client_detail`, `group_member`, and `group_detail` are the structures required.


int main()
{
    struct group_detail *group_details = malloc(0 * sizeof(*group_details));
    struct client_detail *client_details = malloc(1 * sizeof(*client_details));
    int size = 0;
    int j = 0;
    while(j < 100){
        client_details = realloc(client_details, (size + 1) * sizeof(client_details));
        j++;
        size++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The above piece of code works perfectly fine, but if I put the stuff that I am doing in while in a function, the loop terminates on the 11th iteration with an error `malloc: *** error for object 0x147606ac0: pointer being realloc'd was not allocated`.

Below is the code with the function which throws error:-

```
void func(struct client_detail *client_details,int *size){
    client_details = realloc(client_details, (*size + 1) * sizeof(*client_details));
    *size = *size + 1;
}

int main()
{
    struct group_detail *group_details = malloc(0 * sizeof(*group_details));
    struct client_detail *client_details = malloc(1 * sizeof(*client_details));
    int size = 0;
    int j = 0;
    while(j < 100){
        func(client_details,&size);
        j++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I am running the above code on macOS.

I initially was doing it in a modular way, which didn't work. I tried the non-modular way(w/o functions) and it works properly. I want it to work properly even with the functions. I am not able to figure out why it's not working.

Hope someone can help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function is not updating the caller's value of client_details, you need one more level of pointer:

```
void func(struct client_detail **client_details,int *size){
    *client_details = realloc(*client_details, (*size + 1) * sizeof(**client_details));
    *size = *size + 1;
}

int main()
{
    struct group_detail *group_details = malloc(0 * sizeof(*group_details));
    struct client_detail *client_details = malloc(1 * sizeof(*client_details));
    int size = 0;
    int j = 0;
    while(j < 100){
        func(&client_details,&size);
        j++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Similar as with size, if you just wanted the value, the type would be `int`. Changing an `int size` variable inside the function would not have any effect on the caller. You want to change it, so you make a pointer to int `int *` and dereference it to read/write the value.

With `void func(struct client_detail *client_details,int *size){` you are getting the client_details pointer by value and changing that will have no effect on the caller's variable. You need to add a pointer-to-it similar as was done for size.